# Subir y redimensionar imagen PHP

Tags: php

Tengo un problema, no puedo redimensionar las imágenes que subo. Sí puedo subirlas, pero cuando se pasan de un tamaño quería redimensionarlas a la mitad o tal vez bajar el ancho y el alto a 300 x 300.

Adjunto código que utilizo para subir la imagen. Existe un `if` que chequea el tamaño de la imagen si se supera muestra el mensaje "Lo siento, el archivo es demasiado grande". En vez de eso quería, directamente, redimensionar la imagen.

```
<?php

$target_dir = "uploads/";

$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

//Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if ($check !== false) {
        echo '<script>alert("Archivo es una imagen - " . $check["mime"] . ".")</script>';
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo '<script>alert("Archivo no es una imagen.")</script>';
        $uploadOk = 0;
        echo '<script>location.href="media.php"</script>';
    }
}

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {

    echo '<script>alert("El archivo ya existe .")</script> ';
    $uploadOk = 0;
    echo '<script>location.href="media.php"</script>';
}
// ****Aqui necesito redimensionar si supera el tamaño en el if****
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 800000) {
    $nueva = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"];
    $porcentaje = 0.5;
    list($ancho, $alto) = getimagesize($nueva);
    $nuevo_ancho = $ancho * $porcentaje;
    $nuevo_alto = $alto * $porcentaje;
    //Redimensionar
    $imagen_p = imagecreatetruecolor($nuevo_ancho, $nuevo_alto);
    $imagen = imagecreatefromjpeg($nueva);
    imagecopyresampled($imagen_p, $imagen, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nuevo_ancho, $nuevo_alto, $ancho, $alto);
    return $imagen;
    // echo '<script>alert("Lo siento , el archivo es demasiado grande.")</script> ';
    // $uploadOk = 0;
    echo '<script>location.href="media.php"</script>';
}
// Allow certain file formats
if ($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png") {
    echo '<script>alert("Lo siento , solo archivos con extensión JPG y PNG ")</script> ';
    $uploadOk = 0;
    echo '<script>location.href="media.php"</script>';
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo '<script>alert("Lo siento, su archivo no ha sido cargado.")</script> ';
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo '<script>alert("El archivo ha sido cargado")</script> ';
        $nombre = basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

        $extension = $imageFileType;
        require_once 'data/conexion.php';

        $sentencia = "INSERT INTO  media (file_name, file_type, id_area) VALUES ('$nombre', '$extension', '$id_area2')";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sentencia);
        mysqli_close($conn);
        mysqli_free_result($result);

        echo '<script>location.href="media.php"</script>';

    } else {
        echo "Perdon , error al subir el archivo , vuelva a intentarlo.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Estás usando `return $imagen` sin ser una función y, además, `$imagen` es un recurso que representar a la imagen en formato interno, debes usar alguna función para convertir dicha imagen en un archivo y que sea ese archivo el que se trate. Además, quizá deberías usar  `$imagen_p` que es la imagen que has creado en la que reduces la original.

Comment: Deberia crear una función resize() debajo de todo el codigo y llamarla debajo del if ?

Comment: Te he puesto una solución rápida, en la que guardas el contenido de `$imagen_p` en el mismo archivo que subieron y cambias el valor de `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"]` de acuerdo al nuevo tamaño.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplificándolo mucho, el problema que sufres es que no haces nada ni con `$imagen` ni con `$imagen_p`, por lo que el trabajo que haces lo pierdes.

Una solución muy sencilla sería o bien sobreescribir la imagen subida o bien crear una imagen en un directorio temporal:

```
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 800000) {
    $nueva = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"];
    $porcentaje = 0.5;
    list($ancho, $alto) = getimagesize($nueva);
    $nuevo_ancho = $ancho * $porcentaje;
    $nuevo_alto = $alto * $porcentaje;
    //Redimensionar
    $imagen_p = imagecreatetruecolor($nuevo_ancho, $nuevo_alto);
    $imagen = imagecreatefromjpeg($nueva);
    imagecopyresampled($imagen_p, $imagen, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nuevo_ancho, $nuevo_alto, $ancho, $alto);
    /* Sobreescribimos la imagen original con la reescalada */
    imagejpeg($imagen_p, $nueva);
    /* Actualizo el tamaño al que tiene la imagen reescalada */
    $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] = filesize($nueva);
 }
```

Comment: Funciona Oscar, muchas gracias, pero pregunto  debería mover ese bloque IF de tamaño al final ?, si te fijas tengo otras condiciones que vienen después como que si es jpg o png

Comment: Quizá deberías hacer un bucle que vaya reduciendo la calidad del JPEG si supera el máximo de 800000 bytes y si llegada a una calidad mínima (20, por ejemplo) no consigues tener menos de 800 KB, generar un fallo.

Comment: Pero podria especificar por ejemplo 400x400 ancho y alto y me aseguro que la imagen nunca va a ser demasiado baja en su calidad en vez del porcentaje?

Comment: En ese caso, en vez de forzar 400x400, que provocaría que la imagen "se encogiera" a lo ancho o a lo alto si no es cuadrada, te recomiendo que calcules qué es más grande, el alto o el ancho, y dependido de ello ajustes el otro parámetro manteniendo la relación de aspecto. Creo que el tema merece dedicación, deberías crear una nueva pregunta para ello.

Comment: Perfecto Oscar y de nuevo  muchas gracias!!:)