# Al capturar una foto en php enviarla con una tamaño mas pequeño

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo un formulario en php pero con html el cual tiene un formulario para enviar información y ademas se le agregó tres input tipo file para cargar tres fotografías que toman desde el celular o desde el mismo computador, pero al tomar las fotos desde el celular y subirlas se demoran mucho tal vez por el tamaño de la foto o resolución, la idea que pregunto es que si es posible cuando yo tome la foto y este en el file para enviar, desde el php que tengo para guardar la informacion a la BD de mysql poder que se reduzca el tamaño automaticamente a uno menor y carge mucho mas rapido. adjunto el html y el de php:

```
<?php 

session_start();


    include "../conexion.php";

    if(!isset($_SESSION["user"])){ //Si no ha iniciado sesión redirecciona a index.php
        header("Location: ../index.php");
    }

        $usuario_id = $_SESSION['idUser'];
        /*  $rol                = $_SESSION['rol']; */
        $name_id    = $_SESSION['nombre'];

 ?>

<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" charset="UTF-8">
        <?php include "includes/scripts.php"; ?>
        <title>Nuevo Registro Creación Dirección-Claro Fijo</title>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Courgette' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href="stacktable.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!--    <link href="curso/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="curso/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
        <script src="curso/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="curso/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    .btn_descarga{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: 600;
    /*font-size: 20px;*/
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #1883ba;
    border-radius: 6px;
    /*border: 2px solid #0016b; */
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin-top: 5px;
  }

  .btn_borrar {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: 600;
    /*font-size: 20px;*/
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #680801;
    border-radius: 6px;
    /*border: 2px solid #0016b; */
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    width:50%;
  }

  </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php include "includes/header1.php"; ?>

        <section id="container">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <h1 style="text-align:center"><i class="far fa-edit"></i>Nuevo Registro Creación Dirección - Claro Fijo</h1>
            </div>

            <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="guardar_registro_claro_fijo.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">

                <div class="form_register">
                    <label for="nombre" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nombre Especialista</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" onKeyUp="document.getElementById(this.id).value=document.getElementById(this.id).value.toUpperCase()" placeholder="Nombre Especialista" required>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form_register">
                    <label for="nom_cordi" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nombre Coordinador</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <select class="form-control" id="nom_cordi" name="nom_cordi">
                            <option value="Angel Rafael Perez Arias">Angel Rafael Perez Arias</option>
                            <option value="Diana Patricia Vargas Hurtado">Diana Patricia Vargas Hurtado</option>
                            <option value="Edwar Bastidas Montenegro">Edwar Bastidas Montenegro</option>
                            <option value="Kevin Nicolas Quintero Ramirez">Angel Gregorio Salgado Leal</option>
                            <option value="Leidys Marcela Saldoval Carvajal">Leidys Marcela Saldoval Carvajal</option>
                            <option value="Luisa Fernanda Laguna Paez">Luisa Fernanda Laguna Paez</option>
                            <option value="Maria Mireya Sanchez Hernandez">Maria Mireya Sanchez Hernandez</option>
                            <option value="Mike Stenven Rodriguez Hernandez">Mike Stenven Rodriguez Hernandez</option>
                            <option value="Wilmer Jose Gutierrez Perez">Nelson Javier Blanco Guanipa</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form_register">
                    <label for="direccion" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Dirección Exacta Lugar de Venta</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="direccion" name="direccion" onKeyUp="document.getElementById(this.id).value=document.getElementById(this.id).value.toUpperCase()" placeholder="Dirección Venta" required>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form_register">
                    <label for="nombre_cliente" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nombres del Cliente</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre_cliente" name="nombre_cliente" onKeyUp="document.getElementById(this.id).value=document.getElementById(this.id).value.toUpperCase()" placeholder="Nombres del Cliente" required>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form_register">
                    <label for="documento" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Número de Documento</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="documento" name="documento" onKeyUp="document.getElementById(this.id).value=document.getElementById(this.id).value.toUpperCase()" placeholder="Número de Identificación" required>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form_register">
                    <label for="number" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Teléfono/Celular</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="telefono" name="telefono" onKeyUp="document.getElementById(this.id).value=document.getElementById(this.id).value.toUpperCase()" placeholder="Número Telefono" required>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form_register">
                <!--    <label for="vendedor">Vendedor</label>  -->
                <label for="number" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Asesor</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="vendedor" id="vendedor" placeholder="Vendedor" value="<?php echo $name_id = $_SESSION['nombre'];?>" readonly="true" required>
                </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form_register">
                    <label for="archivo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Subir Imagen No.1</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="archivo" name="archivo" multiple="">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form_register">
                    <label for="archivo1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Subir Imagen No.2</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="archivo1" name="archivo1" multiple="">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form_register">
                    <label for="archivo2" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Subir Imagen No.3(Opcional)</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="archivo2" name="archivo2" multiple="">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form_register">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <a href="lista_vendedor_tp_claro_fijo.php" class="btn_borrar">Regresar</a>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn_descarga">Guardar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
<?php 

session_start();


    include "../conexion.php";

    if(!isset($_SESSION["user"])){ //Si no ha iniciado sesión redirecciona a index.php
        header("Location: ../index.php");
    }

 ?>

<?php

    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $nom_cordi = $_POST['nom_cordi'];
    $direccion = $_POST['direccion'];
    $nombre_cliente = $_POST['nombre_cliente'];
    $documento = $_POST['documento'];
    $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];


    $sql = "INSERT INTO personas (nombre, nom_cordi, direccion, nombre_cliente, documento, telefono) VALUES ('$nombre', '$nom_cordi', '$direccion', '$nombre_cliente', '$documento', '$telefono')";

    //$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
    //$id_insert = $mysqli->insert_id;
    $resultado = $conection->query($sql);
    $id_insert = $conection->insert_id;

    if (!isset($_FILES["archivo"]) || $_FILES["archivo"]["error"] > 0){
    //if($_FILES["archivo"]["error"]>0){ //este es el bueno
        echo "</br>Error al cargar Imagen No.1</br></br>";  
        } else {

    //  $permitidos = array("image/gif","image/png","image/jpg","image/jpeg","application/pdf");
        $permitidos = array("image/gif","image/png","image/jpeg","image/jpg","video/mp4","audio/amr");
        $limite_kb = 16384;

        if(in_array($_FILES["archivo"]["type"], $permitidos) && $_FILES["archivo"]["size"] <= $limite_kb * 1024){

            $ruta = 'files/'.$id_insert.'/';
            $archivo = $ruta.$_FILES["archivo"]["name"];

            if(!file_exists($ruta)){
                mkdir($ruta);
            }

            if(!file_exists($archivo)){

                $resultado = @move_uploaded_file($_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"], $archivo);

                if($resultado){
                    echo "</br>Imagen Guardada No.1</br></br></br>";
                    } else {
                    echo "</br>Error al guardar Imagen No.1</br></br>";
                }

                } else {
                echo "</br>Archivo ya existe</br></br>";
            }

            } else {
            echo "</br>Imagen No.1 no permitida o excede el tamaño</br></br>";
        }

    }

?>

<?php 
// Para Envio de Imagen Numero Dos
if (!isset($_FILES["archivo1"]) || $_FILES["archivo1"]["error"] > 0){
    //if($_FILES["archivo"]["error"]>0){ //este es el bueno
        echo "Error al cargar Imagen No.2"; 
        } else {

    //  $permitidos = array("image/gif","image/png","image/jpg","image/jpeg","application/pdf");
        $permitidos = array("image/gif","image/png","image/jpeg","image/jpg","video/mp4","audio/amr");
        $limite_kb = 16384;

        if(in_array($_FILES["archivo1"]["type"], $permitidos) && $_FILES["archivo1"]["size"] <= $limite_kb * 1024){

            $ruta = 'files/'.$id_insert.'/';
            $archivo = $ruta.$_FILES["archivo1"]["name"];

            if(!file_exists($ruta)){
                mkdir($ruta);
            }

            if(!file_exists($archivo)){

                $resultado = @move_uploaded_file($_FILES["archivo1"]["tmp_name"], $archivo);

                if($resultado){
                    echo "Imagen Guardada No.2";
                    } else {
                    echo "Error al guardar Imagen No.2";
                }

                } else {
                echo "Archivo ya existe";
            }

            } else {
            echo "Imagen No.2 no permitida o excede el tamaño";
        }

    }


?>

<?php 
// Para Envio de Imagen Numero Tres
if (!isset($_FILES["archivo2"]) || $_FILES["archivo2"]["error"] > 0){
    //if($_FILES["archivo"]["error"]>0){ //este es el bueno
        echo "Error al cargar Imagen No.2"; 
        } else {

    //  $permitidos = array("image/gif","image/png","image/jpg","image/jpeg","application/pdf");
        $permitidos = array("image/gif","image/png","image/jpeg","image/jpg","video/mp4","audio/amr");
        $limite_kb = 16384;

        if(in_array($_FILES["archivo2"]["type"], $permitidos) && $_FILES["archivo2"]["size"] <= $limite_kb * 1024){

            $ruta = 'files/'.$id_insert.'/';
            $archivo = $ruta.$_FILES["archivo2"]["name"];

            if(!file_exists($ruta)){
                mkdir($ruta);
            }

            if(!file_exists($archivo)){

                $resultado = @move_uploaded_file($_FILES["archivo2"]["tmp_name"], $archivo);

                if($resultado){
                    echo "Imagen Guardada No.3";
                    } else {
                    echo "Error al guardar Imagen No.3";
                }

                } else {
                echo "Archivo ya existe";
            }

            } else {
            echo "Imagen No.3 no permitida o excede el tamaño";
        }

    }


?>


<html lang="es">
    <head>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" charset="UTF-8">

        <?php include "includes/scripts.php"; ?>
    <title>Registro Guardado Direcciones Claro Fijo</title>

        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

        <style>
    .btn_descarga{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: 600;
    /*font-size: 20px;*/
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #1883ba;
    border-radius: 6px;
    /*border: 2px solid #0016b; */
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin-top: 5px;
  }

  .btn_borrar {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: 600;
    /*font-size: 20px;*/
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #680801;
    border-radius: 6px;
    /*border: 2px solid #0016b; */
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    width:50%;
  }

  </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <?php include "includes/header1.php"; ?>

        <section id="container">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="row" style="text-align:center">
                    <?php if($resultado) { ?>
                        <h3>Registro Guardado</h3>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                        <h3>Error al Guardar o No se Subió Imagen</h3>
                    <?php } ?>

                <!--    <a href="lista_vendedor_tp_claro_fijo.php" class="btn btn-primary">Regresar</a>-->

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="row" style="text-align:center">
                    <a href="lista_vendedor_tp_claro_fijo.php" class="btn_descarga">Regresar</a>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

No se si me pueden ayudar con este caso. Gracias

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Subir y redimensionar imagen PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/322771/subir-y-redimensionar-imagen-php)

Answer (score 0):

Puede haber 2 problemas.

Cliente: El desarrollo web está orientado a la arquitectura cliente-servidor. Si tarda mucho en subir las imágenes lo que puedes hacer es bajarle la resolución(Con su consiguiente perdida de calidad), cambiarle el formato(No todos los formatos ocupan lo mismo), comprimir todas las fotos que quieras subir y mandarlas todas en un archivo que se descomprimirá en el servidor o una mezcla de todas. Pero todo esto se hace desde el cliente (Usando JavaScript) si no quieres mandar toda la información por la red. Ya que si tienes

Las ventajas son que no sobrecargas tanto la red (Generas menos tráfico) y por lo tanto estaría bien para conexiones más lentas, lo que aumentaría el rendimiento.

Las desventajas son que pierdes calidad o tamaño en las imágenes que, en caso de que la reduzcas de tamaño, es irrecuperable.

Servidor: La otra posibilidad es que sea la conexión del servidor web con la base de datos la que sea lenta(Ambos no tienen porque estar en la misma máquina) lo cual implica que los mismos métodos de reducción o compresión de imágenes se haga en el servidor(Usando php) para que a la hora de guardarlo en la base de datos sea más liviano.

Las ventajas son que si la conexión servidor web con el servidor de la base de datos es lenta, mejoras el tiempo de respuesta.

Las desventajas son que el servidor va a sufrir el procesamiento todo que quieras hacer y eso provocará que si el servidor tiene que hacer muchas operaciones por segundo (En caso de servidores comerciales) coja unos recursos valiosos. Otra desventaja es que solo optimizarías desde el camino del Servidor web -> Servidor de bases de datos pero no el de cliente -> Servidor web, que en la mayoría de los casos es el que más latencia mete a las conexiones.

Mi consejo, tratalas como quieras en el cliente para mandarlas por HTTP y ahorres tiempo en todas las fases cliente -> servidor web -> servidor bases de datos y además liberes al servidor de hacer tareas, lo que libera recursos hardware. Además si usas HTTP, no HTTPS, puedes usar cifrados en los archivos para que no sean cogidos por la red o si los comprimes poner contraseña para que, en caso de ataque man in de middle, el atacante solo tenga un chorro de bytes y no tus fotos.

Espero haber sido aclaratorio.

Te adjunto un post para redimensionar imágenes desde PHP: https://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/codigo/PHP/1051-Redimensionar-imagen-JPG-PNG-o-GIF.html

Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, considera revisar [answer], saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con algo así.

```
list($ancho, $alto) = getimagesize($_FILES["datosImagen"]["tmp_name"]);

$nuevoAncho = 500;
$nuevoAlto = 500;

$aleatorio = mt_rand(100, 999);

if($_FILES["datosImagen"]["type"] == "image/jpeg"){

    $ruta = "la/ruta/de/tu/foto/".$_POST["idUsuario"]."/".$aleatorio.".jpg";



    $origen = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES["datosImagen"]["tmp_name"]);

    $destino = imagecreatetruecolor($nuevoAncho, $nuevoAlto);

    imagecopyresized($destino, $origen, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nuevoAncho, $nuevoAlto, $ancho, $alto);

    imagejpeg($destino, $ruta);

}
```

Si ya quieres incluir también formato png repite el proceso con un if y cambias

```
if($_FILES["datosImagen"]["type"] == "image/png")
```

Ojala sea lo que buscas.